# Asp.Net IPN Listener (Successful but DB not updating)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, paypal, paypal-ipn

Here is my IPN listener, all of my purchases are successful but when it comes to updating the database, nothing happens. I'm not even attempting to use any of the data from the post, just a simple 'Test' insertion.

```
    [HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult> Ipn()
{

    var ipn = Request.Form.AllKeys.ToDictionary(k => k, k => Request[k]);
    ipn.Add("cmd", "_notify-validate");

    var isIpnValid = await ValidateIpnAsync(ipn);
    if (isIpnValid)
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO paypal(transaction_id) VALUES('Test')", con);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }

    return new EmptyResult();
}

private static async Task<bool> ValidateIpnAsync(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> ipn)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {


        const string PayPalUrl = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";

        // This is necessary in order for PayPal to not resend the IPN.
        await client.PostAsync(PayPalUrl, new StringContent(string.Empty));

        var response = await client.PostAsync(PayPalUrl, new FormUrlEncodedContent(ipn));

        var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        return (responseString == "VERIFIED");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `isIpnValid` is `true` ?

Comment: I should of mentioned, I've tested this as false as well. Paypal also shows perfect responses, with no retries.